# Download zip file, unzip and save to isolated storage wait complet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I found this example for Download zip file, unzip and save to isolated storage 
(http://transoceanic.blogspot.it/2011/08/wp7-download-zip-file-unzip-and-save-to.html)

I have to wait for the completion of the operation

how can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for"?

Comment: You should "wait for" a few days for the author of that blog post. If you're lucky you'll get an answer straight from him. If not, reformat your question so it can be answered. Meanwhile, this might come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414137/httpwebrequest-download-file-and-progress-bar :)

Comment: the operation is asynchronous. I want an event to tell me the end of the operation

Comment: I hope you tried to implement such events and you will show us the results. So we'll be able to help you with your problem.